# User event SelectedIndexChanged does not take DataBinding new row

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

I have a DDL linked with a binding source. Lets say in the binding source I have 3 rows;

1 - One
2 - Two
3 - Three

When I select the first row, within the method SelectedIndexChanged thw Current BindingSource row is null. Then if I select the second row the current row is the previous one, the first until the SelectedIndexChanged is returned.

Is there a way to get the current row while in SelectedIndexChanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)ddl.DataSource;

string result = dt.Rows[ddl.SelectedIndex]["col_name"].ToString();
```

Comment: I need more information than the displayed ones, thats why i used a binding source!

Comment: try the above code, i have edited it , this might work for you.